# Highcharts : cross symbol with fillColor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, highcharts

However, I can not change the background of the cross (like the triangle symbol)!
Is there a solution?

```
marker: {
    symbol: 'cross',
    fillColor: 'white',
    lineWidth: 4,
    lineColor: 'green',
    states: {
        hover: {
            fillColor: 'white', 
            lineWidth: 6
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a fiddle:
[Fiddle with cross symbol](http://jsfiddle.net/T6tdp/)

Comment: How are angularjs and cordova relevant tags?

Comment: Your symbol returns line, so it is not shape, as a reuslt your fill color cannod be adapted,because where should be?

Comment: Yes, but how can I get the same result as the triangle symbol? 
At least, is it possible to have the same style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @SebastianBochan says in his comment, the defined "cross" symbol is just two lines, there is no fillable region:

```
return ['M', x, y, // move to position
        'L', x + w, y + h, // line to position
        'M', x + w, y, // move to position
        'L', x, y + h, // line to position
        'z']; // close the shape, but there's nothing to close!!
```

[image]

To make a fillable X, you need a shape with an area.  Here's my quick attempt:

```
var distance = w/2;

return ['M', x - distance, y, 
        'L', x, y,
        'L', x + w/2, y + h/2 - distance/3,
        'L', x + w, y,
        'L', x + w + distance, y,
        'L', x + w, y + w/2,
        'L', x + w + distance, y + h,
        'L', x + w, y + h,
        'L', x + w/2, y + h/2 + distance/3,
        'L', x, y + h,
        'L', x - distance, y + h,
        'L', x, y + h /2,
        'L', x - distance, y,
        'z']
```

Will produce a shape like this:

[image]

Which, while not perfect, is fillable...

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/T6tdp/1/).

Answer (score 2):

I have created a fillable cross which is inspired from this post itself. The cross is very similar to Microsoft's ASP chart's cross symbol (my objective was to replicate that cross symbol).

Here is what I have done :

```
Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols.cross = function (x, y, radius) {
    var r = radius * 0.4,
        e = r * 0.8,
        a = e / Math.sqrt(2),
        p = r / Math.sqrt(2);
    return [
        'M', x, y + a,
        'L', x + p, y + a + p,
        x, y + a + (2 * p),
        x + a, y + (2 * a) + (2 * p),
        x + a + p, y + (2 * a) + p,
        x + a + (2 * p), y + (2 * a) + (2 * p),
        x + (2 * a) + (2 * p), y + a + (2 * p),
        x + (2 * a) + p, y + a + p,
        x + (2 * a) + (2 * p), y + a,
        x + a + (2 * p), y,
        x + a + p, y + p,
        x + a, y,
        'Z'];
};
```

I hope it helps someone.